# TestNG - Importing / running tests from different classes

Tags: java, testng

My scenario is:

```
public class ExampleTest extends AbstractExampleTest {
    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"someMethodFromAbstractExampleTest"}
    public void firstTest() {
        // Assert
    }

    // here I would like to call CommonTests
}

public class CommonTests {
    @Test
    public void sharedTest() {
        // Assert
    }
}
```

The reason something like CommonTests exists, is that it will contain a repeated test sequence. The way I currently communicate information from ExampleTest to CommonTests is done via statics which seems to work, but probably not the best.

This works fine if I call CommonTests programmatically according to the TestNG documentation. The issue I have with that is the results aren't logged within the runner of ExampleTest.

```
@Test
public void actionBasedTest(ITestContext context) {
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { ExampleAction.class });
    testng.addListener(tla);
    context.getSuite().addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
}
```

The above is slightly better, but the reporting back is limited to something like "org.testng.TestRunner@####" and doesn't expose the test methods run.

So my question is: can I run tests from another class(es) (not via inheritance) and get the results logged to the same listener?

EDIT: I want to avoid testng.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your last question , you can run tests of any classes using a testng.xml which allows you to structure your tests any way you like.  You can specify your listener in the suite tag and that would be the listener used for all your classes.  Refer this for [examples](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml).

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true. I would ideally like to avoid the use of testng.xml though.

Comment: Just curious, what's the reason?

Comment: I was thinking it would be nice to be able to run the test without that extra requirement (i.e. run the class directly from IDE). In a build environment it would be fine.

But I am going to start playing around with the XML though. I think the IDE integration is there, so it's not a big hassle.